# Automatic monthly Forecast based on daily values

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs, forecast

I want to do a forecast model in excel, which automatically calculates the expected monthly values of a certain variable.

**Table A (Output table):**

here, I want to show the expected end of month value for a patientF.ex. I want to forecast the total value of X for Person A for the whole month of October

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zckhi.png)

**Table B (Data table):**

Here, I receive a daily import from an SQL database with the relevant Person Data for that day
F.ex. on the 15.10.2021 I would receive the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wkJw.png)

**In short, I would like to do the following calculation in my output table B:**

- Return Value of "Number of X", given that "Patient" =Person A for the MM/YYYY match (if successful, this should show 13 for person A/October in the output table)
- Secondly, I want the above value to be divided by the number of days of that particular date (so 15 days in this example)
- Thirdly, I want to multiply it by the total number of days for that given month (as indicated in the Output table/Date section)

I have tried different sumifs/array formulas but I really struggle with one consolidated formula. Any help/tips much appreciated!

Comment: Try the forecast() function. Had luck with that before, using various modifications to tune it as needed.

Comment: Thanks Mike, will look into that one!